# Raspberry pi GPIO output working but not input

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am facing a strange problem. My raspberry 3B+ working all fine but only facing issue in GPIO. I'm using RPi.GPIO library to access gpio pins. The strange thing is I'm not able to read any of the input logic, but all output can be set and all outputs are working fine.

In GPIO.BOARD configuration i have connected 17th pin (i.e 3.3V) to 16th pin. When i read 16th pin it always shows low. I even tried with many other pins like 3,7,16 etc...

my code as below

```
import RPi.GPIO as a
a.setmode(a.BOARD)
a.setwarnings(False)
a.setup(16,a.IN)
while (True):
    if a.input(16):
        print('high')
    else:
        print('low')
```

verified with DMM that about pins are getting 3.3V

Comment: First, I think it is better if you add `sleep(0.1)` in your `while`-loop. Second, it is recommended to call `GPIO.cleanup()` just before leaving your script.

Comment: Can you enable pull up or pull down resistors and check ? This can be due to floating values .

Comment: even i have checked it with pull up and pull down

Answer (score 0):

### This answer is just an attempt to make you realize the good practices.

It is always a good practice to use  built in pull up or pull down resistors of the raspberry pi when reading the state of a digital pin.

When you are providing the 3.3v direct input from 17th pin , the state of the pin 16 is defined clearly. However, when there is no input , you haven't defined any state at all.

Code snippet for it is as shown below.

```
a.setup(16,a.IN,pull_up_down=a.PUD_DOWN) #for pull down resistor 

a.setup(16,a.IN,pull_up_down=a.PUD_UP) #for pull up resistor
```